# Adjusted one sample test with logistic regression

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, standardization, clinical-trials

Suppose I have a performance benchmark to beat from an established study. In this study sample, 60% of the patients belonged to stratum A, and 40% belonged to stratum B, and the performance in A was 70% and in B it was 40%.

I am going to conduct a small uncontrolled study and test the hypothesis that my performance is better than the weighted average performance in the established study. To do this I will randomly sample from the population, but I cannot be assured of the distribution of the strata in my sample, and so the proportion belonging to stratum A may be 30% or 50% (and 70% or 50% respectively for stratum B).

It may be possible that the As do much better in my sample while the Bs do a little worse, or vice versa, but essentially I want the *average* performance to show superiority before I do any further analysis. The issue is one of essentially standardizing the distribution of the strata to the established study to prevent any variability in sampling from leading to incorrect inference.

I understand that if I fit the logistic model with expectation given by

$$ \text{logit}(p) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 S$$

with $S$ being a binary indicator for membership in stratum B, the intercept term is interpreted as the log-odds of response for patients in stratum A. *However* the intercept term is not independent of the slope term.

Therefore if I test the hypothesis that $$ \mathcal{H}_0 : \beta_0 > \log(0.4/ (1-0.4))$$ will this tell me anything about the possible superiority of treatment?

*alternately*

if I constrain $\beta_1$ according to the log-odds ratio obtained from the established study ($\log(\frac{0.4 \times 0.3}{0.6 \times 0.7})$), does the one sample test of $\beta_0 > \log(0.4/ (1-0.4))$ tell me that my average performance is better than the established study?

*and if so for either case*

Does this suffer the issue of using prediction-at-the-means?